# Return a record from PHP with function and render

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function

I have a function

```
function getUser($linkedInID) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ipadapi.users WHERE linkedInID = '".$linkedInID."'";
    $results = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in User SQL query.");
    return $results;
}
```

and this is called via

```
    $returnedUser = getUser($linkedInID);

    // Generate the array for the JSON String
    $returnedMessage = array(
        'status' => 'ok',
        'error' => false,
        'avatar' => $returnedUser['avatar'],
        'userSelectedTheme' => $returnedUser['userSelectedTheme'],
        'checksum' => $checksum
    );

    // JSONify the string and return it
    $returnedJSON = json_encode($returnedMessage);
    echo $returnedJSON;
```

However the results of `$returnedUser['(field name']`Althought,  are always coming up NULL. avatar, userSelectedTheme are some of the fields from the dbase. I have confirmed in the database the infomation is there

I suspect I am missing a key line from my function which involves =array() somewhere and manflu is preventing me seeing it.

Any advice greatly appreicated

Comment: are you sure, that you haven't a typo in userSelectedTheme (in your mysql table column) ?

Comment: Don't use `mysql_` functions anymore. They are deprecated ! Use PDO or mysqli instead. And make your script SQL injection proof.

Comment: You're not looping through the return and fetching the necessary array.

Comment: to get your array with mysqli have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all those who answered, and extra plaudits to those who spotted the use of the depreciated mysql commands.

Had a shot of espresso and got the answer working (albeit unsafe and unsecure and..)

```
function getUser($linkedInID) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ipadapi.users WHERE linkedInID = '".$linkedInID."'";
        $results = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in User SQL query.");

        $arr = array();
        while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
            $arr['avatar'] = $row['avatar'];
            $arr['userSelectedIndustry'] = $row['userSelectedIndustry'];
        }
        return $arr;
    }
```

and the call

```
    $returnedUser = array();

$linkedInID = filter_var($_REQUEST['linkedInID'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);  
        $returnedUser = getUser($linkedInID);

        // Generate the array for the JSON String
        $returnedMessage = array(
            'status' => 'ok',
            'error' => false,
            'avatar' => $returnedUser['avatar'],
            'userLinkedInIndustry' => $userLinkedInIndustry,
            'userSelectedTheme' => $returnedUser['userSelectedTheme'],
            'userSelectedIndustry' => $returnedUser['userSelectedIndustry'],
            'checksum' => $checksum
        );

        // JSONify the string and return it
        $returnedJSON = json_encode($returnedMessage);
        echo $returnedJSON;
```

many thanks for all time spent, and apologies for not just getting my head down and figuring it out

Comment: I won't let you go until you replace `'".$linkedInID."'"` by `'".(int)$linkedInID."'"` xD

Comment: LOL - noted. But linked in ID example = 'Zcw297e3Qw' so not all numbers. I will (just for you) see what capabilities this dusty old server has and build in some injection protection just for you and appreicate the care and attention, but there is a SHA1 checksum function that has a secret key that only the mobile and API have, and this key is NOT stored in the dbase for retreival

Comment: Well, you could use `filter_var($linkedInID, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)` in that case. Even if it is not stored, it is still a security hole. A big one. If by any method one could get this variable to contain `0'; DELETE * FROM ipadapi.users;` ... You get the idea.

Comment: Updated my answer with the new sanitised variable. Very nice workaround, thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all stop using `mysql_`([Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)) is deprecated.

`mysql_query` from `getUser` function returns a resource. you must
return an array. so have a look at `mysql_fetch_array` or `mysql_fetch_assoc` functions

basically you must return  `mysql_fetch_array($results)` assuming that is only one result comming from db. otherwise you'll have to loop through them.

Comment: Old server, running old php, running.. you get the picture. Upgrade is awaiting approval and whole new everything will be done in April, I am just working with the tools given so a mobile dev can start some work with data returned from the databases, but well spotted as this is always great advise. phpStorm was basically screaming at me, fading the command out, putting lines through it and everything =)

Comment: @MOLEDesign You should at least cast your `$linkedInID` variable with `(int)` to prevent injections.

Comment: Its a combo of letters and numbers. There are two SHA1 checksum tests that run before any SQL is accessed with a secret key etc so there is a level of security where API just bombs out of the checksum fails. The chksum is nothing to do with the Database basically Mobile generates and posts a value, api generates the value, if they match the process proceeds. . I am going to just test the new mysql commands now to see if they implode the system, but the version of MYSQL on this server is ancient (hosts joomla 1.5 early version before they started using MYSQLi)

Answer (score -1):

```
$data=array();
while($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
data[]=$row;
}
return $row;
```

Comment: Well, that's a really low quality answer